# For Loop not working in route.config in MVC4

Tags: asp.net

I am working on MVC 4 Application and Mapping the URL in route.config.. 
I want to make the route with 50 different route names for which i want to run a for loop in route.config something like this..

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
 {


string routeChildLink = "URLRoute" + i.ToString();
  string pathChildLink = menuSubChild.pageid.ToString() + "/" + menu.title.Replace(" ", "_") + "/" + menuChild.title.Replace(" ", "_") + "/" + menuSubChild.title.Replace(" ", "_") + "/" + i;
  routes.MapRoute(routeSubChildLink, pathSubChildLink, new { controller = "home", action = "index" });

 }
```

But when I run the Site it through an error stating "A route named 'URLRoute1' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique."
The For loop is not working.

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: where is `routeSubChildLink`, `pathSubChildLink` come from?

Comment: i didn't get any error. let me know how they occur? please post complete code...

Comment: @jzm: routeSubChildLink is name and pathSubChildLink is URL

Answer (score 0):

Use

Routing debugger to see what routes are being created and called

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

It looks like that loop is being called second time.
MapRoute table have URLRoute1 in it already.

Answer (score 0):

**The Framework always tries to match the URL of the request to a route in the order of the Routes added to the RouteCollection.**

So you should put the custom routes before the default route,

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
            {
                string routeChildLink = "URLRoute" + i.ToString();
                //Custom route
                routes.MapRoute(
                                   name: "Route name",
                                   url: "URL with parameters",
                                   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "MethodName" }
                               );
            }

            //default route
            routes.MapRoute(
                            name: "Default",
                            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                        );
        }

    protected void Application_Start()
            {
                AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

                RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
                RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            }
```